# Android listView styling

Tags: android, listview, styling

I want to change text color of the list item ,below is my code

```
 public class HelloListView extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.list);

  this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name));    


       ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

  }); }}
```

> My List.xml

```
 <  LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <ListView  
     android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 


     />
 <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Empty set"
      />
 < /LinearLayout  >
```

Thanks :)

Comment: when do you want to change the text colour? when it's clicked? for every item? You need to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using an android built-in row component as a view for each row :

```
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

If you want to customize it, pick the code and put your own version in your app. The original code can be found on [google code project for android](http://code.google.com/p/and-bookworm/source/browse/trunk/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml?spec=svn242&r=242) :

Then you can customize xml and change the color attribute or change for a new selector state.

If you want to something even more custom, override your list's adapter getView method and provide a custom component inflating this xml and providing additional methods to be filled and display your data for each row.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the appearance of the elements in the list, Use the CustomListView and CustomAdapter.

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-2

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html

This Links may help you......